# Cannot dynamically populate table using $_SERVER AUTH_USER

Tags: javascript, php, authentication

I am currently having an issue with my php intranet site where I am trying to dynamically load user stats into a table using 'AUTH_USER' for the username.

Windows Authentication is set up on the server (IIS 8), and when I run the following, the logged in user shows correctly.

```
<?php
    $user = $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'];
    echo "$user";
    ?>
```

When I attempt to dynamically populate using AUTH_USER the table displays no information at all.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://exampleserver/content/widgets/widgets.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var pcUsername =  '<?= $_SERVER['AUTH_USER'] ?>';
      var pcServerURL = 'http://exampleserver';

      pcGetUserDetails();
    </script>
            
                            
                        <h3>Test Widget</h3>
    <div id="customwidget">
      <table style="border: solid 1px black;">
        <tr>
          <th>Username:</th>
          <td id="userName"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Balance:</th>
          <td id="userBalance"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Restricted:</th>
          <td id="userRestricted"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Pages:</th>
          <td id="userPages"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Jobs:</th>
          <td id="userJobs"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>CO2:</th>
          <td id="userCO2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Trees:</th>
          <td id="userTrees"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Bulb Hours:</th>
          <td id="userBulbHours"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th>Since Date:</th>
          <td id="userSinceDate"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      document.getElementById('userName').innerHTML = pcUsername;
      if (pcUserDetails.balanceFormatted != undefined) {
        document.getElementById('userBalance').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.balanceFormatted;
        document.getElementById('userRestricted').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.restricted;
        document.getElementById('userPages').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.printStats.pages;
        document.getElementById('userJobs').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.printStats.jobs;
        document.getElementById('userCO2').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.environmentalImpact.gramsCO2Formatted;
        document.getElementById('userTrees').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.environmentalImpact.treesFormatted;
        document.getElementById('userBulbHours').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.environmentalImpact.bulbHoursFormatted;
        document.getElementById('userSinceDate').innerHTML = pcUserDetails.printStats.sinceDateFormatted;
      }
    </script>
```

I have checked and the table correctly pulls the users data if I manually add the name. For example

```
var pcUsername =  'testuser1';
```

correctly populates the data for the 'testuser1'. I have also tried $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and it does not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.